# How to parse a config file with tab indented options with sed?

Tags: sed

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
        option type 'mac80211'
        option hwmode '11g'
        option path 'platform/soc/a000000.wifi'
        option legacy_rates '1'
        option mu_beamformer '0'
        option country 'US'
        option channel '1'
        option vendor_vht '1'
        option htmode 'HT20'
        option txpower '13'

config wifi-device 'radio1'
        option type 'mac80211'
        option hwmode '11a'
        option path 'platform/soc/a800000.wifi'
        option htmode 'VHT80'
        option country 'US'
        option mu_beamformer '0'
        option txpower '16'
        option legacy_rates '0'
        option channel '60'
```

For example, I want to find `radio1 > channel`(in this example 60) in this config file and replace it with 99, can I do it with sed? or some other linux tools?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better served using `awk`, but rather than editing in-place, you will need to redirect the output to a temporary file and then copy the temporary file over the original. The choice of `awk` has to do with its ability to use variables within the script. That way you can flag when `config wifi-device 'radio1'` is found and replace only the next occurrence of `option channel`. You can do that with:

```
awk '
    $0 ~ /config wifi-device [[:punct:]]radio1[[:punct:]]/ { found = 1 }
    found && $1 == "option" && $2 == "channel" { 
        sub(/[0-9]+/,"99")
        found=0
    }
    1
' file
```

Where `sub()` is used to replace the numbers in the occurrence of `option channel` with the updated value `99`. The `1` is just shorthand for the default command "print" so each line is output.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example config in the file named `file`, you would get:

```
$ awk '
>     $0 ~ /config wifi-device [[:punct:]]radio1[[:punct:]]/ { found = 1 }
>     found && $1 == "option" && $2 == "channel" {
>         sub(/[0-9]+/,"99")
>         found=0
>     }
>     1
> ' file
config wifi-device 'radio0'
        option type 'mac80211'
        option hwmode '11g'
        option path 'platform/soc/a000000.wifi'
        option legacy_rates '1'
        option mu_beamformer '0'
        option country 'US'
        option channel '1'
        option vendor_vht '1'
        option htmode 'HT20'
        option txpower '13'

config wifi-device 'radio1'
        option type 'mac80211'
        option hwmode '11a'
        option path 'platform/soc/a800000.wifi'
        option htmode 'VHT80'
        option country 'US'
        option mu_beamformer '0'
        option txpower '16'
        option legacy_rates '0'
        option channel '99'
```

Which replaces `60` with `99` for the channel as desired. You then just redirect the output to a temporary file by adding  `> temp` after `file` and you can review `temp` before copying it over the original config when you are satisfied it is correct. (you can automate that adding the compound command `&& cp temp file` at the end, but I generally like to review changes -- up to you)

**note:** if you want to match the single quotes exactly in the regular expression you could use the octal or hex codes for `'''`, e.g. `\047` or `\x27`. You would quote and escape the single-quotes in the replacement string, e.g. `"'\''99'\''"`. Given your wifi config file and ability to isolate the line and replacement without them, you can likely safely omit those steps as they do make the script a bit less readable.

Comment: Well explained awk solution

Answer (score 1):

`sed "/^config.*radio1/,/channel/s/channel.*/channel '99'/" config-file`

In the range from `config.*radio1` to `channel`, replace `channel.*` with `channel '99'`

Comment: The range command is tricky. It does not reset until the end condition is met (which maybe never). In this example it is probably ok but if there were two or more configs for radio1 and the first did not have a channel entry, the next channel entry would match. This may be another config other than radio1 and thus not what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed "/^config /h;G;/channel.*radio1/s/\S\+/'99'/3;P;d" file
```

Make a copy of each config header line in the hold space.

Append the latest config header line to each line.

If the current line contains both `channel` and the required config, substitute the third field with the required value.

Since each line now represents two lines, only print the first and delete the rest.